# Outlook Accounts - How to get the Exchange Email address?

Tags: c#, exchange-server, office-interop, outlook-addin

I iterate through all the email accounts in Outlook.
I can get the email addresses of POP and IMAP accounts but I don't get the email address of MS Exchange accounts.

Here is my code:

```
    foreach (Outlook.Account account in accounts) {
        Debug.Print("DisplayName: " + account.DisplayName);
        Debug.Print("UserName: " + account.UserName);
        Debug.Print("CurrentUser.Address: " + account.CurrentUser.Address); //email address or long Exchange address
        Debug.Print("CurrentUser.Name: " + account.CurrentUser.Name);
        Debug.Print("CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address: " + account.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address);
        Debug.Print("DeliveryStore.DisplayName: " + account.DeliveryStore.DisplayName);
    }
```

Here are the results for a non-Exchange account:

```
DisplayName: Edgar Test Account
UserName: Edgar Tester
CurrentUser.Address: edgar@testtest.com
CurrentUser.Name: Edgar Tester
CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address: edgar@testtest.com
DeliveryStore.DisplayName: Edgar Tester
```

And for Exchange:

```
DisplayName: User Name
UserName: 000300KJDFA6220
CurrentUser.Address: /O=FIRST ORGANIZATION/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP(FYDIAASFDSFLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=00458787FA6220
CurrentUser.Name: /O=FIRST ORGANIZATION/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP(FYDLKHHKLSPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=0054654DFA6220
CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Address: /O=FIRST ORGANIZATION/OU=EXCHANGE ADMINISTRATIVE GROUP(FYDIDADS23SPDLT)/CN=RECIPIENTS/CN=0058876220
DeliveryStore.DisplayName: User Name
```

(I changed a few numbers and letters to anonymize this)

**I want the email address of the Exchange account. How can I get this?**

Comment: From your examples it would appear that all Exchange accounts have `DeliveryStore.DisplayName` equal to `DisplayName`. Is this always true and false for non-exchange accounts?

Comment: @Attersson: I am pretty sure these names are independent from each other. But if users use the default names then it's the same. And I don't really care about that name. I want the email address!

Comment: Yes, I was only following some train of thought in order to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Exchange accounts, use `account.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress`.

Comment: I confirm this works with "real" MS Exchange accounts. Until now I thought MS live.com accounts work like Exchange accounts but this is not the case, at least not here. Above code shows an error with MS live.com accounts!

Comment: yes, GetExchangeUser() will return null for the non-EX address entries.

Comment: Follow up question: I have two xxx@live.com accounts. For one account CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser() returns a value and I can use above code. For another yyy@live.com account CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser() returns NULL. Any idea why and how to "fix" this?

Comment: In that case, you can use CurrentUser.Address

Answer (score 0):

Try [ExchangeService.ResolveName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.resolvename(v=exchg.80).aspx)  :

```
//ExchangeService service; //you have some service in your code.

NameResolutionCollection nameColl = service.ResolveName(CurrentUser.Name, ResolveNameSearchLocation.DirectoryOnly,true);
```

Tweak with the parameters a little bit.